# Would contingently inhabited sets be necessarily impure?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory

Allow that ur-elements can count as purely set-theoretic, depending on which ones are introduced (we might say: an ur-element is pure if the only extralogical facts about it feature just the elementhood relation and no other relations). Now, if it is contingent whether some pure ur-element is an element of some set, does that set have to count as impure?

The only substantial treatments of this subject that I've found are a [blog post](http://alexanderpruss.blogspot.com/2016/09/contingent-sets.html) (by a professor) and, indirectly, Christopher Menzel's [essay on "modal set theory"](https://philarchive.org/archive/MENMST). The blogger doesn't really come to any conclusions, he just brings the question up at some length and gives an attempted example of how to apply the notion; Menzel writes early in the essay:

> Intuitively, however, extensionality is not a contingent matter, a mere matter of happenstance. Rather, there simply *couldn’t* have been distinct sets that shared all their members; there is no such possible world.

From the remainder of the essay in as much detail as I have read it, I get that the main thrust of Menzel's reference to modality is to characterize a neo-Zermelian account of *V*/the class of all sets/w/e-along-that-line as an "unfinished totality." He seems to portray *V* as inhabited on the its "upper side" *in potentia*, as though what elements it has *actualiter* changes somehow. However, by a reflection argument (assuming that this property is not generically identifying for *V*), there would seem to be (pure) sets, then, that also contingently have some of their (pure) elements.

**Depending on how we portray the reason for a set to have or lack contingent inhabitants, is there anything essential to the definition of "impurity" that would make any such set impure?** Suppose it were simply random whether some contingently inhabited set is actually inhabited; it is not even the abstract will (by means of forcing, say) of any mathematician that deposits an element in such a set, or mines elements therefrom, and permanently or not, it is random that it remains inhabited (or not) thereafter, too.

Comment: If we assume that the reason for a set to have or lack contingent inhabitants is random, then it is not clear whether this would make the set impure or not. On the one hand, the randomness might be seen as introducing an extralogical relation that goes beyond the membership relation. On the other hand, the randomness might be seen as an intrinsic property of the set itself, in which case the set would still be pure.

Comment: Another aspect is: once you declare a set pure or impure, can you derive anything from that? If not, the notion is not useful.

Comment: @Frank two applications I have in mind: an "objective" subset forcing, where forcing really changes which elements are in which powerset, and so there is a contingent version of ℝ that satisfies an alternative version of CH according to which ℵ1 is the only aleph that *necessarily* goes with ℝ's actual inhabitation. Second: if you scaffold some set theory with a deontic logic, you could say things like **OB** (*A* ∈ *B*), yet then if **OB** implies *contingently*, we would get a contingent set.

Comment: Very nice applications! Seems useful after all.